# Hola estoy realizando una consulta a 2 tablas diferentes, pero no me esta funcionando

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, post

ESTE ES EL CODIGO DE LA VISTA

```
 <div class="content content-full text-center">
                <h2 class="font-w400 text-primary-dark mb-50 invisible" data-toggle="appear" data-class="animated fadeInUp" data-timeout="250">Aquí puede realizar la consulta de sus trámites</h2>
                    
                <form class="push" method="post">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite en código de expediente" name="codigo_consulta">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    $consulta = new ControladorConsultaExpediente();
                    $consulta -> ctrConsultarExpediente();
                    ?>
                </form>
                <!-- AQUI SE MOSTRARÁ EL RESULTADO DE LA CONSULTA -->
            </div>
```

ESTE ES EL CODIGO DEL CONTROLADOR
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ESTE ES EL CODIGO DEL MODELO (el cual no me esta funcionando necesito ayuda porfa)

```
  /*===============================================================
                CONSULTA DE EXPEDIENTE
================================================================*/

static public function mdlConsultaExpediente($tabla1, $tabla2, $item, $valor){
    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT $item FROM $tabla1 INNER JOIN $tabla2 ON $tabla1.$item=$tabla2.$item");

        $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);

         $stmt -> execute();
       

        return $stmt -> fetch();

        $stmt -> close();

        $stmt = null;
}
```

ESTAS SON LAS TABLAS A CONSULTAR LA PRIMERA ES LA TABLA DE expedientes digital Y LA OTRA ES expediente digital jurídico

[image: Esta es la tabla expediente digital]

[image: Esta es la tabla de expediente digitaljuridico]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor, evita las mayúsculas sostenidas, que se entiende como que gritas

Comment: cuando pongo el codigo me vota error el editor de stackoverflow

Comment: Como con tu pregunta, que nos digas "bota error" no nos dice nada para ayudarte con tu pregunta.

Comment: a que te refieres?

Comment: @ALEXIJUNIORARIASSARAVIA edita tu pregunta y agrega codigo, ademas se mas especifico en tu descripcion sobre lo que quieres realmente

Comment: voy a editar mi pregunta y le pondre el codigo

Comment: en realidad solo pasaba 3 parametros, la tabla, el item y el valor, esto cuando solo consultaba a  una tabla, pero ahora deseo realizar la consulta a 2 tablas, y es por eso que le paso un parametro más

Comment: Nono men.. no entiendes, no necesitas de parametros, puedes hacer la consulta en bruto. El único parámetro dinámico que veo, es `$valor`

Comment: entonces el item y las tablas las puedo manejar de forma estática? y ya del controlador solo envio el valor como parametro

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente **nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Sería recomendable (y no ahuyentarás a los compañeros) "copiar y pegar" el código en el editor que poner capturas de pantalla.

Comment: Si ya le dijimos sobre el codigo, no es necesario el testamento entero nuevamente.

Comment: estoy editando mi pregunta, ya le puse codigo pero el del controldor no logro poner

Comment: @Excorpion podrias entrar a este servidor de dicord y ayudarme porfa https://discord.gg/QbwHAnWa

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, quiero llamar la atención a la función:

```
function mdlConsultaExpediente($tabla1, $tabla2, $item, $valor){
    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT $item FROM $tabla1 INNER JOIN $tabla2 ON $tabla1.$item=$tabla2.$item");
        $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        // $stmt -> execute();
        return $stmt -> fetch();
        $stmt -> close();
        $stmt = null;
}
```

Por alguna razón, esta función esta recibiendo demasiados parámetros, los cuales son estáticos. Dado que:

```
$tabla1 = "expediente_digital";
$tabla2 = "expediente_digital_juridico";
$item = "codigo_expediente";
```

El único parámetro que es dinámico, es `$valor`:

```
$valor = $_POST['codigo_consulta"];
```

Por lo que podemos trabajar la consulta de una manera mucho más simple:

```
SELECT ed.codigo_expediente FROM expediente_digital ed INNER JOIN expediente_digital_juridico edj ON ed.codigo_expediente = edj.codigo_expediente
```

Obviamente, podemos validar la consulta, ejecutandola directamente en la base de datos y viendo que resultados obtenemos. Ahora...
Que se supone que estás queriendo hacer acá:

```
$stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Posteriormente a eso, haces un return... y lo que entiendo tampoco, son las siguientes lineas...

```
    $stmt -> close();
    $stmt = null;
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118426/discussion-on-answer-by-excorpion-hola-estoy-realizando-una-consulta-a-2-tablas).